# AJAX call to remote server - which path? URL

Tags: ajax, hosting

Please see UPDATE at the bottom.

---

I am using 1and1 to publish my (first) site (that I gladly got lots of help from this comunnity - thanks!). 
It's all perfect at my localhost.

Bottom line of the question:

Host: 1and1

Ajax: URL ?

How to debug a page on the net (as opposed to my localhost)?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Here are the pieces of code:

```
$.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : '/homepages/23/d97025366/htdocs/sodabrasil/php/locationsJsonBrasil.php',
                    dataType : 'json',

                    success: function( json ){
                            neighborhood=[];
                            infobubbles=[];

                            $.each(json,function(i,item){
                                neighborhood.push(new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat,this.lng));
                                contentString = ({link:this.link,name:this.name,lat:this.lat,lng:this.lng,link:this.link, web:this.web, city:this.city, youtube:this.youtube, state:this.state, country:this.country})
                                infoBubble = new InfoBubble (contentString)
                                infobubbles.push(infoBubble)


                         });    //$.each
```

Here is the json file:

```
<?php

 require 'config.php';

try {

    $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    $sth = $db->query("SELECT * FROM globalstories");
    $locations = $sth->fetchAll();

    echo json_encode( $locations );

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

and finally the config file

```
<?php  
 $server    = 'dbXXXXXXXX.db.1and1.com';
 $username  = 'dboXXXXXXX';
 $password  = 'password';
 $database  = 'dbXXXXXXXXX';
 $dsn       = "mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database";
```

### ?>

**UPDATE**

I have been trying this for a couple of days now. Even added a different company, now  Bluehost. 
The page is [here](http://www.braaasil.com). Please click on "*sem fronteiras*". That's that only link with files now.

The picture for firebug and exlplorer is here. [image: here]. It seems it is not reading the map. But if I delete the config and point config and  ajax url to my computer, everything works again. 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is your actual root URL; i.e. www.MyWEbsite.com.  You are using your entire `/homepages/23/d97025366/htdocs/sodabrasil/php/locationsJsonBrasil.php` address but it's likely only `php/locationsJsonBrasil.php` or something like that.

Comment: i tried that because that's how it set up for localhost. Added "/" at the beginning, etc. Didn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: If it works on local and not on your server then it's either a pathing issue or the file doesn't exist.  So, just be sure you are trying to access the correct address.  Hit F12 in Google Chrome and go to your Network panel to see which page it's actually requesting and whether or not it failed.

Comment: see **UPDATE** at main question. Thank you for you time!

Comment: It's hard to say since you're not getting any errors...  I suggest creating a new blank page and try to put ONLY your map on it.  That way, you can isolate the issue.

Comment: I actually loaded other parts of the page, like log in and it is pushing the map. It's the database connection. I can't get it right, something wrong with the config.php file or the ajax url.

Comment: You've got to give us something better to go on if you want our help.  You have to give us some code that is producing an error message or something along those lines.